# event does not publish in redis in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, redis, laravel-echo

I want to develop real-time app with laravel echo and redis
but it doesn't work
ie: when I fire event nothing happened
I check redis is ok but I don't know how can I correct this problem

event:

```
   class testevent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $data;
/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
  $this->data="sdf";

}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{

    return ['testCh'];
}
}
```

fire:

```
  Route::get('test',function ()
 {
event(new testevent());

return 1;

 });


⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!
```

js file:

```
 import Echo from "laravel-echo"
 window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'socket.io',
host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
    });
console.log("sdfsdffdnpm")
window.Echo.channel('testCh')
.listen('.testevent', () => {
    console.log("sooooooooooooooooo");
});
```

Comment: change `.testevent` to `testevent`

Comment: no it doesnt work @AdnanMumtaz

Answer (score 1):

> config/app.php make sure you have

```
     App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

> in your .env

```
  BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
```

run `php artisan queue:listen`

I hope this helps